# Additional loader to handle Mapbox

Tags: typescript, react-native, mapbox, loader, babel-loader

I am currently creating an app that will use Mapbox. For this I use the package @rnmapbox/maps.

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/src/web/utils/Logger.ts 2:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */
> type LogMessage = {
|   level: LogLevel;
|   message: string;
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand what to do.

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You're consuming the dependency directly as typescript source. If that's intentional, you have to configure your tools to compile the package as if it were your own source code. By default typescript and babel will ignore everything in node modules, as they are assuming it is already transpiled.